# Intercept GNU/Linux system calls

Tags: virtual-machine, make, system-calls, open-files

## Context

I am trying to design a tool that would more or less automatically generate a Makefile from a standard shell script.

The idea would be that for each command executed by the script: I register the files that are read from and written to, then generate the associated dependencies in a Makefile along side with the associated command. I do not want to limit the scope of such command, they could be: a compiler call in an esoteric language, a test suite, a packaging system, etc...

In practice, the Makefile is only a cache for the tool. It provides a suggestion of commands that can run in parallel. The first run will assume complete sequential dependency and observe which files are read/written by which command. The following runs only run commands that need to be re-run, with a mechanism *à la* make.
The subtlety is that if a command is trying to read a file that is not up-to-date yet (new dependency), the intercepted call will stall until the file is updated.

## Problem

I need to intercept, in real time, access to files to detect which files are accessed by which command.

I did consider using `LD_PRELOAD`, but this assume all commands use `libc` calls to perform system calls. And I considered implementing my own kernel module to capture those system calls but then my tool will require undue permissions.

I see two solutions:

- run the commands in debug mode
- run the commands in a virtual environment using OS virtualization capabilities

*Would debug mode provide me with enough control to intercept those calls?* For instance, would it stack with a command that already run a sub-process in debug mode?

*If not, how much work would involve using virtualization capabilities of the processor?* That is, the virtualized operating system is mostly transparent (except for the stalling behavior), will I need to implement a lot of unrelated system calls?

## Assumptions

I am only interested in files accessed by user space commands, if a program is run in privileged mode I do not expect to be able to "spy" it.
I will assume a file is either produced/updated by exactly one command or it is a seed.

Comment: Why not use `strace -fe open`?

Comment: Kind of meta to your question: what you describe seems like a solution searching for a problem.  There are already way too many build environments, helpers, generators, make-alike programs, and what not.  None of these tools use a shell script to do their work.  So why would anybody use your tool, instead of using one of these make-alike programs, or indeed writing a plain `Makefile`?

Comment: To do something similar to what you want to do, the [installwatch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installwatch) program uses LD_PRELOAD, I believe.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Plain `Makefile`s need to be maintained in parallel of the code. It is one of the main reason why most people use generators (tracking header files is redundant work). I am not aware of generators that are language oblivious. I believe it is possible to make one in such a straight forward way that it could simply take a bash script. Note that if I catch all system calls I could get rid of the "bash script" requirement and bootstrapping the system from a `Makefile` would be feasible.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thank you for the reference, I didn't know this tool. Indeed, `installwatch` relies on `LD_PRELOAD` to catch `libc` function calls. I guess it is probably sufficient for my use case. But there are much more libc function calls manipulating files than linux system calls.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `strace` do not allow me to stall process. But you are right in suggesting I look at how they do it. Thanks.